# how is the decision taken at run time whether to call derived class function or base class function?

Tags: c++

How is the decision taken internally (during runtime) as to which function to call, either the base class or derived class function. In the below sample code how is decision taken to call **fn()** of **B** and **fn2()** of **A**.

```
Class A { 
    virtual void fn() { std::cout << "A" < <std::endl; }
    virtual void fn2() { std::cout << "A-fn2" < <std::endl; }
    };

Class B : A
{
    void fn() { std::cout << "B" < <std::endl; }
}

int main() {
    B b = new B;
    A *a = &b;
    a->fn();
    a->fn2();
}
```

The output would be **B** and **A-fn2()**

Basically how is the decision taken at run time whether to call derived class function or base class function?

Comment: That cannot possibly compile, right? Also, you might want to look at [vtables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table)

Comment: I forgot to add the Virtual keyword. Apologies for that. **Can you explain in detail how the the decision is taken** the interviewer was particular to know the internal implentaion. He hinted some thing called **Virtual Tables**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is known as **Dynamic/Run-time polymorphism**.
The rule is:
**The method to call at run-time is selected at run-time, depending on the actual object pointed to by the pointer.**
How the compiler does this is completely implementation dependent. Typically, your code should only rely on the behaviors and not the internals of this. However, all known compilers implement this mechansim through a virtual table(`vtbl`) & virtual pointer(`vptr`) mechanism.

**How is run-time polymorphism implemented?**

Once a class has an `virtual` method that class is known as a polymorphic class and the compiler creates a `vtbl` for that class. The `vtbl` stores the addresses of all virtual methods in that class. The compiler also adds a special pointer `vptr` to every object of that class. The `vptr` points(stores the address of) to the `vtbl`.
Once a class derives from such a polymorphic class, the compiler replaces the addresses of methods in the `vtbl` of the derived class with the address of overidding functions in the derived class.For non overidden methods the addresses are still that of the Base class methods.

Thus, Each class has typically one `vtbl`, while each object instance has a `vptr`, which points to the `vtbl`. The `vtbl` of each class stores address of its *own* virtual methods.

At run-time, the `vptr` inside the `this` pointer is fetched and further the appropriate method address in the `vtbl` is fetched & then it is called, this mechanism is called *dynamic dispatch*.
Thus, due this mechanism the appropriate method to be called can be determined depending on *type* of the object which the pointer points to.

This C++-Faq is a good further read:
**[Inheritance — virtual functions](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html)**

Answer (score 1):

After correcting the compilation errors, the answer for your question is that the output will be:
**A A-fn2**.

There is no `virtual` function present in your code which needs any runtime decision making. Compiler itself will evaluate calls for the function.

Suppose you make the `A`'s methodss `virtual` then the function call decision making at runtime happens based upon the *which object is referred to*.

Comment: I forgot to add the Virtual keyword. Apologies for that. **Can you explain in detail how the the decision is taken** the interviewer was particular to know the internal implentaion. He hinted some thing called **Virtual Tables**

Comment: @NiklasB.: While it is good to point out that this is implementation dependent, **All** known compilers implement dynamic dispatch through virtual table & pointer mechansim,So the argument though correct is not really valid.

Comment: @Als: That's why I've written an answer about vtables. cheers.

Comment: @NiklasB., what you have suggested in your answer could be correct for popular pattern for vtables. However compiler is free to choose whatever they want, until the observable behavior doesn't change for the virtual functionality.